# Can't get vue-awesome working with vue.js

Tags: font-awesome, vue-cli

I am using vue-cli (6.3.0), node (10.8.0) and npm (6.3.0) and have set up a basic project using this tutorial [Build your first vue.js components](https://frontstuff.io/build-your-first-vue-js-component) I came to add vue-awesome

$ npm install vue-awesome
$ npm install

and I can see that vue-awesome has been added to package.json

I have a file componets/rating.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
   <ul>
     <li><icon name="star"/></li>
     <li><icon name="star"/></li>
     <li><icon name="star"/></li>
     <li><icon name="star-o"/></li>
     <li><icon name="star-o"/></li>
   </ul>
   <span>3 of 5</span>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import 'vue-awesome/icons/star'
 import 'vue-awesome/icons/star-o'

 import Icon from 'vue-awesome/components/Icon'

 export default {
   components: { Icon }
 }
</script>
```

and main.js is,

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import Rating from './components/Rating'
Vue.config.productionTip = false
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<Rating/>',
  components: {
    Rating
  }
})
```

npm run dev

gives me this error,

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors
>   7:11:40 PM
>
> This dependency was not found:
>
> - vue-awesome/icons/star-o in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/Rating.vue
>
> To install it, you can run: npm install --save
>   vue-awesome/icons/star-o

So I ran $ npm install --save vue-awesome/icons/star-o

this gives me

> npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL npm ERR! Could not install from
>   "vue-awesome/icons/star-o" as it does not contain a package.json file.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /Users/shanegibney/.npm/_logs/2018-08-15T18_18_10_343Z-debug.log

Any help on what might be causing this would be very much appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `regular/star` :

```
<v-icom name='regular/star'></v-icon>
```